# PHP sort nested array by arbitrary string

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an interesting challenge.  I have an array that looks like this:

```
array(
 [1] = array(
   'fruit' => 'Banana'
 ),
 [2] = array(
   'fruit' => 'Apple'
 ),
 [3] = array(
   'fruit' => 'Grapes'
 )
)
```

I need to sort the array according to fruit, presuming the fruit have this priority:

#1: Apple

#2: Banana

#3: Grapes

Ultimately the output should be:

```
array(
 [2] = array(
   'fruit' => 'Apple'
 ),
 [1] = array(
   'fruit' => 'Banana'
 ),
 [3] = array(
   'fruit' => 'Grapes'
 )
)
```

Would this be done by some sort of usort() trickery?

Comment: Yes, it _would_ be done with `usort()`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: If you can move the values to the 1st level it might be easier with array_intersect, then merge with difference

Comment: The main thing that is throwing me off is the nested-ness.  There are a bunch of other attributes in each node.  Have been trying different things with usort but it's not coming out correctly yet.

Comment: Did you try array_multisort()?  Kinda what it's for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to keep the index association:

```
foreach($array as $key => $values) {
    $fruit[$key] = $values['fruit'];
}
array_multisort($fruit, SORT_ASC, $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example using usort:

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    array(
        'fruit' => 'Banana'
    ),
    array(
      ' fruit' => 'Apple'
    ),
    array(
        'fruit' => 'Grapes'
    )
);

function sortByFruit($arr1, $arr2)
{
    if ($arr1['fruit'] == $arr2['fruit']) {
        return 0;
    } elseif ($arr1['fruit'] < $arr2['fruit']) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

usort($arr, 'sortByFruit');
```